# How can I get the user from my AuthorizationAttribute from within an ASPNETCORE 2.2 application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, httpcontext, authorize-attribute

I have created a custom attribute that I would like to decorate my api controller from within my ASPNETCORE angular application. I am able to set up my authentication as required and log into the application from the login. Then I decorate my api method with my custom attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]
public class ManageAuditAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public List<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
    public ManageAuditAttribute(String feature)
    {
        Feature = feature;
    }
    public bool IsAuthorized()
    {
      // TODO check there is a claim for the given feature
    }
    private String Feature { get; }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var accessor = (IHttpContextAccessor)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor));
        var name = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email); //NULL
        var user = context.HttpContext.User; // NULL
        var userName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name; // NULL
    }
}
```

Before saying that claims are not used this way I would add that I need to fit this into a legacy system that has a list of allowed features. I am adding those features to the user as claims and checking the claim exists for each user. The value for the actual claim is the name of the application that the user needs the claim for.

I could easily add these as a custom list to my custom identity user which might be more fitting however, I still need to access my user.

I can get the user but the name is always null and my claims list is empty as well.  It is as if I am not logged in at all. Even after logging in.

Comment: Have you add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` or `services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` this in your configure service method?

Comment: The accessor is not null, just the user

Comment: Okay! Let me check!

Comment: Did you make sure that you are loggged in?

Comment: I went through the login process and seems to be logged in. I can refresh and not get redirected to login after my initial login.

Comment: Would you show me your startup class code?

Comment: I have run your `ManageAuditAttribute` code in a test project! Its working fine!

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x87I1r

Comment: all the pieces are in here I think https://dotnetfiddle.net/3WVMU3

Comment: I see your `Configure` method missing `app.UseAuthentication();` add this just before `app.UseMvc().` and let me know the result.

Comment: Okay, I will try this

Comment: User is not null but the name is null

Comment: What returns this line `var name = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);`?

Comment: That returns  null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186576/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-jwize).

Comment: Do I need to use JWT token authorization for ajax requests?

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving name, you should pass `ClaimTypes.Name` instead of `ClaimTypes.Email` like

```
var user = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);
```

Or, you could retrieve by `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` like

```
var userName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: The credentials are not there even though the user is in the database so something else is wrong.

Comment: @jwize Share us the attach windows for `context.HttpContext.User` and check the available properties

Comment: Inexplicably, it has started working. The only thing I have changed which upon testing with Tanvir who kindly offered some help was adding a setting to AddAuthenticaiton(however, in our tests the value was still coming up null). Context.HttpContext.User is getting the correct information as originally expected.

Comment: @jwize Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Okay, the user is empty again. This makes so little sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved you problem by adding:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

in Startup.cs.